# Post thumbnail not working after regenerate

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I have this setting in function.php

```
add_image_size( 'thumbnail-gallery', 185, 185, true );
```

It will display a square picture.

Everything is fine before I regenerate new size using "Regenerate Thumbnails" plugin.

After the process finished, the `<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail-gallery' ); ?>` will return the original "big" url instead the regenerate url.

it does not crop. original file url. not square.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `wp-content/uploads/` directory. Does your cropped image exists there? (e.g. `myimage-185x185.jpg`). If not, you could try to call `add_image_size()` on the `init` action hook.

**functions.php**

```
function wpse27579_addImageSizes() {
    add_image_size('thumbnail-gallery', 185, 185, true);
}
add_action('init', 'wpse27579_addImageSizes');
```

Comment: yes. the generated images are there in wp-content. but WordPress just scale the image using css.

Answer (score 0):

This work beautifly for me:

`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

`set_post_thumbnail_size( 200, 300 );`

`add_image_size( 'thumbnailGallerySmall', 145, 120 );`

The Integration Code

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnailGallerySmall');?>
```

Try it.. and good luck